# JGraphT implementation in Android

Tags: java, android, graph, jgrapht

I implemente JGraphT into Android Application.

I have added everything needed into Gradle and after that I wanted to put some examples into code:

```
        SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> topoGraph =
                new SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);
        topoGraph.addVertex("Rysy");
        topoGraph.addVertex("Giewont");

        DefaultWeightedEdge e1 = topoGraph.addEdge("Rysy", "Giewont");
        DefaultWeightedEdge e2 = topoGraph.addEdge("Giewont", "Rysy");

        topoGraph.setEdgeWeight(e1, 200);
        topoGraph.setEdgeWeight(e2, 400);
```

While I want to start my app, I get an error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mountaintraveller, PID: 9857
    java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #226 bootstrap method
        at org.jgrapht.util.SupplierUtil.createSupplier(SupplierUtil.java:60)
        at org.jgrapht.util.SupplierUtil.<clinit>(SupplierUtil.java:38)
        at org.jgrapht.util.SupplierUtil.createSupplier(SupplierUtil.java:60)
        at org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph.<init>(SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph.java:45)
        at com.example.mountaintraveller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
        at org.jgrapht.util.SupplierUtil.createSupplier(SupplierUtil.java:60) 
        at org.jgrapht.util.SupplierUtil.<clinit>(SupplierUtil.java:38) 
        at org.jgrapht.util.SupplierUtil.createSupplier(SupplierUtil.java:60) 
        at org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph.<init>(SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph.java:45) 
        at com.example.mountaintraveller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

where the line: at org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph.(SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph.java:45) is from Graph problem.

I am not able to understand what does mean "Exception from call site #226 bootstrap method" there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this error.
Everything what is needed:

Open yours Gradle file and insert:

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

inside android { ... } options.